# FullCalendar lang doesn't work

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar API (v2.2.0). I initialize my calendar :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      theme: true,
      lang: 'fr',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next, today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      slotDuration: '00:10:00',
      defaultView: 'agendaDay',
      eventLimit: true,
      editable: false,
      eventOverlap: false,
      events: jsonArr,
      axisFormat: 'H:mm',
      timeFormat: 'H:mm'
});
```

I specified the language "fr" but the translation doesn't work completely, **today** stay **today** as well as **month**, **week** and **day**.
[image]
Did I miss something ?

Comment: did you include the language file? Also, be aware if you upgrade your fullCalendar to the latest version this will option will stop working - see  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/lang/ . If you're writing new code, you might as well upgrade now IMHO.

Comment: AbsolutelyI included the language file (if I didn't it will never change to "Lundi" ...) and I included the file from here : https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fullcalendar/2.2.0 but still doesn't work :(

Comment: Sounds odd. It's an old version of fullCalendar now (not even listed in "previous releases" on the website), maybe there's a bug. See the demo at https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.2.0/demos/locales.html for a working example, you can copy that - obviously you'll need to upgrade to 3.2 as part of following that, and use the new "locale" property instead of "lang".

Comment: I upgrade to 3.2 but I had a pb in the style(I donno what's happen). So I return to 2.2! I fixed my problem. I have to use lang-all.js and not fr.js. Thx a lot ;)

Comment: i would guess the stylesheet will have changed somewhat between versions, so if you've used a theme, you'd have to update that too, or if you've done any custom style to override the defaults you'd have to check that too. But at least you fixed the original problem.